# Using VBA To Delete Cells With Zeros

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range that varies where column A and B are being compared to *Column C* and *D*. 
This data is pulled from a pivot table, and so the length of the rows can vary. I have my formula to pull from the pivot tables going through row 130. What I'm trying to do is delete any cells where A and B are both empty or where both C and D are. Unfortunately it's only deleting some of the excess cells then stopping.

Below is the code I'm currently using (any suggestions would be greatly appreciated)

```
 Dim i As Long

 For i = 6 To 200
      If Cells(i, 1) = "0" And Cells(i, 2) = "0" Then
          Cells(i, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
          Cells(i, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
      Else
          If Cells(i, 3) = "0" And Cells(i, 4) = "0" Then
              Cells(i, 3).Delete Shift:=xlUp
             Cells(i, 4).Delete Shift:=xlUp
          End If
      End If

 Next i
```

Comment: Try `For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 6 Step -1`

Comment: It's not getting all of them because you're skipping one every time you delete a row - you need to decrement your counter or work backwords like my original comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, you need to work backwards or decrement your counter when deleting cells.

`For i = 200 to 6 Step -1` is likely all you need to change.

Imagine that the data looks like this:

```
Row    Data
1      5
2      0    <-- Delete Row 2 [i = 2]
3      0
4      7
```

If I delete Row 2, Row 3 shifts up and my counter moves on to row 3 skipping it.

```
Row    Data
1      5
2      0    <-- Skipped
3      7    <-- Row 3 Not Zero [i = 3]
```

If you work backwards, it behaves as it should:

```
Row    Data
1      5
2      0    
3      0    <-- Delete Row 3 [i = 3]
4      7

Row    Data
1      5
2      0    <-- Delete Row 2 [i = 2]
3      7
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thank you so much for not only the answer, but the explanation. I'm trying to teach myself VBA for Excel as I go and hadn't realized it would skip rows!

Comment: @SammyO'Day Since you're new on this site, please have a look these two links: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309951).

Comment: @user1274820 have you tried my code below ? if it helped you mark as answer and upvote

Comment: Pretty sure you tagged the wrong guy - you were looking for @SammyO'Day

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it searches for the last row in ***Column A*** (as you mentioned your number of rows in your PIVOT might change).
F.Y.I it's safer always also to add a reference to the Sheet where the PIVOT is.

```
Dim i As Long

' use this to find the last row in Column A (since number of rows in PIVOT is dynamic
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 6 Step -1

    If Cells(i, 1) = "0" And Cells(i, 2) = "0" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
        If Cells(i, 3) = "0" And Cells(i, 4) = "0" Then
              Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End If

Next i
```